# Access Toit APIs and PubSub from browser

Tags: toit

The documentation of the Toit APIs and PubSub states that the console APIs and PubSub are available through "gRPC API"s.

Is there a way to also access them through the browser? (maybe with web-grpc or just REST APIs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not at the moment.

api.toit.io has CORS restricted to console.toit.io, also GRPC uses HTTP2 so a gateway must be in play to enable such a setup.
for console.toit.io we use web-grpc but this is not open to the public.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - no. PubSub api needs a valid subscription to a specific topic.